# Why I should use thread.join the make the program run normal?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

```
#include<thread>
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;
int a;

void func1(void* vp) {
    a++;
}

void func2(void* vp) {
    cout << a << endl;
}

int main() {
    for (;;) {
        thread t1(func1, nullptr);
        thread t2(func2, nullptr);
        t1.join();//cannot delete
        t2.join();
        Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

If I delete the code:

```
t1.join();
t2.join();
```

The Program will get abort error.

I know t1.join mean that the main thread is waiting for thread t1 completed all code. But why I must use t1.join() to insure the Program run normal?

Answer (score 4):

Simply because it's mandated by the standard. In the destructor for `std::thread`,

> If *this has an associated thread (joinable() == true), std::terminate() is called. [source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread).

This insures that all threads have finished running and that all associated resources are properly cleaned up. This is not limited to `main`. Any time a thread object is destroyed, it must not be joinable.

See [std::thread:detatch](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) if you want to allow a thread object to be destroyed without joining.

Comment: Note that the purpose of `std::thread::detach` is **not** to allow a thread object to be destroyed without joining. It's purpose is to allow the thread to run independently of any `std::thread` object. That decision is based on the **role** that the thread has in the program, not on hacking code to avoid an exception from the destructor.